# VueJs not rendering when add <div> tag in <template>

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**My VueJs Init**

I use webpack and initialize the vuejs:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import CarrierList from '../components/carrier/CarrierList';

/**
 * Create a fresh Vue Application instance
 */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {CarrierList},
}).$mount('#app');
```

**My Component:**

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Kontaktperson</th>
            <th>Telefon</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Email Empfänger</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="carrier in carriers">
                <td>{{ carrier.id }}</td>
                <td><a :href="route.generate('carrier_show', {id : carrier.id })">{{ carrier.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ carrier.contact_person }}</td>
                <td>{{ carrier.phone }}</td>
                <td><span v-if="carrier.region">{{ carrier.region.name }}</span></td>
                <td>{{ carrier.email }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a :href="route.generate('carrier_show', {id : carrier.id })"><span class="badge badge-secondary pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Spedition anzeigen"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                    <a :href="route.generate('carrier_edit', {id : carrier.id })"><span class="badge badge-info pointer" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Spedition bearbeiten"><i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: "CarrierList",
    data() {
        return {
            carriers: {},
            route: FosRouting,
            loading: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loading = true
        axios.post(this.route.generate('api_carrier_list'))
            .then(response => {
                // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                this.carriers = response.data
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            });
    },
    methods: {}

}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .loader{  /* Loader Div Class */
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#eceaea;
        background-image: url('/images/ajax-loader.gif');
        background-size: 50px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        z-index:10000000;
        opacity: 0.4;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    }
</style>
```

All is working right, the table will render with all the data that I get from the ajax request.

But now I want to add a simple div (for loading the ajax loading spinner) into the template:

```
<template>
    <div class="loader" v-if="loading"></div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID </th> ....
```

But now, nothing will render. Why? I can't add a  anywhere outside my table element.

**Question:**
What am I doing wrong and how can I add a single simple  outside my table element and vuejs render my CarrierList Template?

**Info:**
I do not get an error in my console - nothing but the template still will not rendering.
When I remove the `<div class="loader" v-if="loading"></div>` the template will render and everything works normal.

Comment: generally, most templates need *one* root element. without the div the table is that element. what *might* work is setting `v-else` on the table, which is probably not, what you visually want. wrapping both in yet another div will work as well.

Comment: Its because you need a container that wraps all elements inside the template. Cant you just wrap another div around the elements in the template.

Comment: yes. thats it. When I wrap another div inside <template><div> ....</div></template> it will work.